# Endpoint for an EJB deployed on JBOSS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I have deployed an ejb in a war file(not an ear file). 
I have successfully consumed an ejb deployed in an ear file previously but now I am getting javax.naming.NameNotFoundException because my EJB is hosted in the war file. If my web app is called SpeechServices and the bean is under com.xyz.ejb package and its name is Service then what will be the JNDI lookup string i should be using?
I am using the following right now.

```
ServiceRemote remote = (ServiceRemote) ct.lookup("SpeechServices/Service/remote-com.xyz.ejb.ServiceRemote");
```

Please help me rectify the error in above statement.

My full code is following, which works to connect to ejbs if they are in an ear,

```
        Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
                "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "admin");
        env.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory");
        InitialContext ct = new InitialContext(env);
        ServiceRemote remote = (ServiceRemote) ct.lookup("SpeechServices/Service/remote-com.xyz.ejb.ServiceRemote");
        System.out.println(remote.parseNotes(null, null, null));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the JNDI to make sure that you are using the right key.  To do this:

1. Access **JBoss:service=JNDIView** in JMX-Console
2. invoke **list()** method
3. Verify whether your EJB is bound properly and confirm that the key you are using is correct

Comment: Thanks a lot, surprisingly it is bound as global JNDI Namespace, so connection string was "Service/remote-com.ecw.ejb.ServiceRemote" no app name to append to? Is this good or bad?

Comment: I don't see any issue with it.  BTW, you can provide your own JNDI name if you don't like the default one.  For custom name, you need to use LocalBinding/RemoteBinding annotations or their XML equivalents.

Comment: You may want to accept the answer if the solution worked for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have updated the web.xml to use

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">
```

I think the spec says that EJBs are not processed in a Java EE 6 way if this isn't done in your web.xml.